# Django: File permissions media and static files

Tags: django, deployment, file-permissions, static-files, supervisord

I use Django with supervisor. My project folder is located in `foouser` directory, however in supervisor, I chose to run the deployment process using a different user, which was created by

```
$ adduser --disabled-login www
```

Hence user www does not have access to the media and static folders of the django project since they are under a different user directory. I feel that just making the file-permissions `0777` is not a proper way for allowing user `www` to have access to the static and media files. I also feel that it might be a security risk to run the deployment process under `foouser` which has more privileges compared to user `www`.

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change owner group of your media directory/files to `www`'s group and give it full permission.

Another option is to put your media files under a directory where `www` user has access, (may be you can use symlink/hardlink to bring directory owned by `www` under your django project media path).

Comment: I like the idea of user groups. Forgot about that. Thanx. The symlink probably won't work because when I do `collectstatic` user `foouser` will have to access to wherever it is writing.